# Failing to copy the /var/www/html directory from nextcloud container to the host

Tags: docker, nextcloud

I am trying to backup the /var/www/html directory from a nextcloud container to the host computer prior to doing a Nextcloud upgrade. From the host, if I say:

```
    docker cp nc-app:/var/www/html .
```

only a subset of the files/directories are copied. For example, within the data directory, only a few files/dirs are copied. Also some single files like index.html are not copied. Is there some option needed with the cp to copy everything or might this be a permission issue of some kind?

Comment: Are you running `docker cp..` command as root?

Comment: Yes. I would love to know the cause of this partial file copy but in the meantime, I decided that I would tar the directory on the container to the host with this command: docker exec nc-app tar Ccfv $(dirname /var/www/html) - $(basename /var/www/html) > /root/extdisk/html.tar

Answer (score 0):

I tar'ed the directory on the container to the host with this command: docker exec nc-app tar Ccfv $(dirname /var/www/html) - $(basename /var/www/html) > /root/extdisk/html.tar